# Merge Hashes within Array of Hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

**I'm generating an array of hashes like this:**

```
hash = Modality.joins(:exam).where(exams: {physician_id: physician}).map {|m|
  {name: m.name, data: {m.exam.from_date => m.total}}
}
```

**The output:**

```
[
  {:name=>"MR", :data=>{Sun, 01 Jan 2017=>44}}, 
  {:name=>"CT", :data=>{Sun, 01 Jan 2017=>7}}, 
  {:name=>"US", :data=>{Sun, 01 Jan 2017=>1}}, 
  {:name=>"MR", :data=>{Wed, 01 Feb 2017=>41}}, 
  {:name=>"CT", :data=>{Wed, 01 Feb 2017=>4}}, 
  {:name=>"MR", :data=>{Wed, 01 Mar 2017=>66}}, 
  {:name=>"CT", :data=>{Wed, 01 Mar 2017=>6}}, 
  {:name=>"XR", :data=>{Wed, 01 Mar 2017=>1}}, 
  {:name=>"CT", :data=>{Sat, 01 Apr 2017=>8}}, 
  {:name=>"US", :data=>{Sat, 01 Apr 2017=>1}}, 
  {:name=>"MR", :data=>{Sat, 01 Apr 2017=>73}}
]
```

**I need to group and merge the data part of the hash based on the name key like this:**

```
[
  {:name=>"MR", :data=>{Sun, 01 Jan 2017=>44, Wed, 01 Feb 2017=>41, Wed, 01 Mar 2017=>66, Sat, 01 Apr 2017=>73}}
  {:name=>"CT", :data=>{Sun, 01 Jan 2017=>7, Wed, 01 Feb 2017=>4, Wed, 01 Mar 2017=>6, Sat, 01 Apr 2017=>8}}
  {:name=>"US", :data=>{Sun, 01 Jan 2017=>1, Sat, 01 Apr 2017=>1, Sun}}
  {:name=>"XR", :data=>{Wed, 01 Mar 2017=>1}}
]
```

**I tried reducing and merging like this:**

```
exams = hash.group_by {|d| d[:name]}.map {|k, v| v.reduce(:merge)}
```

**But it's not the desired output:**

```
[
  {:name=>"MR", :data=>{Sun, 01 Jan 2017=>44}}, 
  {:name=>"CT", :data=>{Sun, 01 Jan 2017=>7}}, 
  {:name=>"US", :data=>{Sun, 01 Jan 2017=>1}}, 
  {:name=>"XR", :data=>{Wed, 01 Mar 2017=>1}}
]
```

How would I correctly merge this hash?

Comment: Hello, in your expected outputs in `data` you mentioned same key multiple times which is not possible in the hash.
 `:data=>{Sun, 01 Jan 2017=>44, Sun, 01 Jan 2017=>44 }`

we can achieve the below output:
`[  {:name=>"MR", :data=>{Sun, 01 Jan 2017=>44, Wed, 01 Feb 2017=>41, Wed, 01 Mar 2017=>66, Sat, 01 Apr 2017=>73}}
  {:name=>"CT", :data=>{Sun, 01 Jan 2017=>7, Wed, 01 Feb 2017=>4, Wed, 01 Mar 2017=>6, Sat, 01 Apr 2017=>8}}
 ]`
but for name `CT` we have diff values on the same date so which value we should keep in that case?

Comment: The reason you are not getting multiple entries in `:data` is that most of  the dates are same

Comment: I've removed the multiple January dates to make my question more clear. Cary Swoveland's answer below is exactly what I was looking for. Any other reason why this question was down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your array `a`, which I've reduced in size and put the dates in quotes.

```
arr = [
  {:name=>"MR", :data=>{"Sun, 01 Jan 2017"=>44}}, 
  {:name=>"CT", :data=>{"Sun, 01 Jan 2017"=>7}}, 
  {:name=>"US", :data=>{"Sun, 01 Jan 2017"=>1}}, 
  {:name=>"MR", :data=>{"Wed, 01 Feb 2017"=>41}}, 
  {:name=>"CT", :data=>{"Wed, 01 Feb 2017"=>4}}, 
  {:name=>"CT", :data=>{"Wed, 01 Mar 2017"=>6}}, 
  {:name=>"XR", :data=>{"Wed, 01 Mar 2017"=>1}},
  {:name=>"US", :data=>{"Sat, 01 Apr 2017=>1}}
]
```

A simple modification is required to convert the date strings to `Date` objects<sup>1</sup>, but I will not do that as the methods below do not depend on whether the dates are strings or `Date` objects.

Here are two ways to obtain the desired return value.

**Use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)**

```
arr.group_by { |h| h[:name] }.
    map { |k,v| { name: k, data: v.reduce({}) { |h,g| h.merge(g[:data]) } } }
  #=> [{:name=>"MR", :data=>{"Sun, 01 Jan 2017"=>44, "Wed, 01 Feb 2017"=>41}},
  #    {:name=>"CT", :data=>{"Sun, 01 Jan 2017"=>7, "Wed, 01 Feb 2017"=>4,
  #                          "Wed, 01 Mar 2017"=>6}},
  #    {:name=>"US", :data=>{"Sun, 01 Jan 2017"=>1, "Sat, 01 Apr 2017"=>1}},
  #    {:name=>"XR", :data=>{"Wed, 01 Mar 2017"=>1}}]
```

Note that `Enumerable#group_by` produces the following hash.

```
arr.group_by { |h| h[:name] }
  #=> {"MR"=>[{:name=>"MR", :data=>{"Sun, 01 Jan 2017"=>44}},
  #           {:name=>"MR", :data=>{"Wed, 01 Feb 2017"=>41}}],
  #    "CT"=>[{:name=>"CT", :data=>{"Sun, 01 Jan 2017"=>7}},
  #           {:name=>"CT", :data=>{"Wed, 01 Feb 2017"=>4}},
  #           {:name=>"CT", :data=>{"Wed, 01 Mar 2017"=>6}}],
  #    "US"=>[{:name=>"US", :data=>{"Sun, 01 Jan 2017"=>1}},
  #           {:name=>"US", :data=>{"Sun, 01 Jan 2017"=>1}}],
  #    "XR"=>[{:name=>"XR", :data=>{"Wed, 01 Mar 2017"=>1}}]}
```

One could alternatively replace

```
v.reduce({}) { |h,g| h.merge(g[:data]) }
```

with

```
v.map { |h| h[:data] }.reduce(&:merge)
```

**Use [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) and [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge)**

```
arr.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g[:name]=>g) { |_,n,o| { name: n[:name], data: n[:data].merge(o[:data]) } }
end.values
  #=> [{:name=>"MR", :data=>{"Sun, 01 Jan 2017"=>44, "Wed, 01 Feb 2017"=>41}},
  #    {:name=>"CT", :data=>{"Sun, 01 Jan 2017"=>7, "Wed, 01 Feb 2017"=>4,
  #                          "Wed, 01 Mar 2017"=>6}},
  #    {:name=>"US", :data=>{"Sun, 01 Jan 2017"=>1, "Sat, 01 Apr 2017"=>1}},
  #    {:name=>"XR", :data=>{"Wed, 01 Mar 2017"=>1}}]
```

This uses the form of `Hash#update` that employs a block for determining the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. See the method's doc for details, particularly the definitions of the three block variables, `_`, `o` and `n`. (The first block variable, which holds the common key, is here represented by an underscore [a valid local variable] to signify that it is not used in the block calculation.)

<sup>1 `require 'date'; arr = a.map do |h|; key, value = h[:data].flatten; h.merge(data: { Date.parse(key)=>value }); end`</sup>

Comment: Appreciate the help. Your solution solved the problem for me. I did have to modify it slightly because I needed the hashes of dates to be combined like so:

exams = hash.group_by {|h| h[:name]}
                .map {|k, v| {name: k, data: v.map {|g| g[:data].flatten}.to_h}}