# Merging & Summing nested hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, chartkick

What I'm trying to do is very similar to the question [outlined in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50382578/merge-hashes-within-array-of-hashes), but I have one additional problem in that the nested values of my hash need to have their dates grouped and the values of each date summed.  The goal is to create a [Multiple Series Graph](https://chartkick.com/#chart-7) in Chartkick.

The query, grabbing a month range for example:

```
arr = LineItem.includes(:order, :product)
              .where(orders: {order_date: Date.parse("Jan 1 2020")..Date.parse("Feb 1 2020")})
              .map { |line_item| { name: line_item.product.model_number, data: { line_item.order.order_date.strftime('%a %b %d, %Y') => line_item.order_quantity } } }
```

The output hash:

```
 => [
{:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Mon Jan 20, 2020"=>2}}, 
{:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Mon Jan 20, 2020"=>5}}, 
{:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>1}}, 
{:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>3}}, 
{:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Wed Jan 22, 2020"=>1}}, 
{:name=>"FR-GP04", :data=>{"Mon Jan 20, 2020"=>2}}, 
{:name=>"FR-GP04", :data=>{"Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>4}}, 
{:name=>"FR-GP04", :data=>{"Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>3}}, 
{:name=>"FR-GP04", :data=>{"Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>6}}, 
{:name=>"FR-GP04", :data=>{"Wed Jan 22, 2020"=>3}}, 
{:name=>"FR-GP01", :data=>{"Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>5}}, 
{:name=>"FR-GP01", :data=>{"Thu Jan 23, 2020"=>3}}, 
{:name=>"FR-GP01", :data=>{"Thu Jan 23, 2020"=>1}}, 
...
```

My expected hash; which should group the name, then group the date and sum the value:

```
 => [
{:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Mon Jan 20, 2020"=>7, "Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>4, "Wed Jan 22, 2020"=>1}}, 
{:name=>"FR-GP04", :data=>{"Mon Jan 20, 2020"=>2, "Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>13, "Wed Jan 22, 2020"=>3}}, 
{:name=>"FR-GP01", :data=>{"Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>5, "Thu Jan 23, 2020"=>4}}, 
...
```

However, after running this code:

```
arr.group_by {|h| h[:name]}.map { |k,v| { name: k, data: v.map {|h| h[:data]}.reduce(&:merge)}}
```

this is the output:

```
 => [
{:name=>"RP-AP02", :data=>{"Mon Jan 20, 2020"=>2, "Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>1, "Wed Jan 22, 2020"=>1}},
{:name=>"RP-AP04", :data=>{"Mon Jan 20, 2020"=>2, "Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>4, "Wed Jan 22, 2020"=>3}}, 
{:name=>"RP-AP01", :data=>{"Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>5, "Thu Jan 23, 2020"=>3}},
...
```

The output generated does group the `name` and `data`, but does not sum the quantities.  I'm grouping it by day here as an example, but would also like the option of grouping it by week & month.  In the past 8 hours of monkeying with this, I've also tried using [Groupdate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to obtain the desired return value. Here are two. First I define `arr`.

```
arr = [
  {:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Mon Jan 20, 2020"=>2}}, 
  {:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Mon Jan 20, 2020"=>5}}, 
  {:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>1}}, 
  {:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>3}}, 
  {:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Wed Jan 22, 2020"=>1}}, 
  {:name=>"FR-GP04", :data=>{"Mon Jan 20, 2020"=>2}}, 
  {:name=>"FR-GP04", :data=>{"Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>4}}, 
  {:name=>"FR-GP04", :data=>{"Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>3}}, 
  {:name=>"FR-GP04", :data=>{"Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>6}}, 
  {:name=>"FR-GP04", :data=>{"Wed Jan 22, 2020"=>3}}, 
  {:name=>"FR-GP01", :data=>{"Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>5}}, 
  {:name=>"FR-GP01", :data=>{"Thu Jan 23, 2020"=>3}}, 
  {:name=>"FR-GP01", :data=>{"Thu Jan 23, 2020"=>1}}]
```

---

The first calculation employs the methods [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values).

```
arr.group_by { |h| h[:name] }
   .map do |k,v|
     { name: k,
       data: v.group_by do |h|
               h[:data].keys.first
             end.transform_values { |a| a.sum { |h| h[:data].values.first }}
     }
end
  #=> [{:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Mon Jan 20, 2020"=>7,
                                  "Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>4,
                                  "Wed Jan 22, 2020"=>1}},
       {:name=>"FR-GP04", :data=>{"Mon Jan 20, 2020"=>2,
                                  "Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>13,
                                  "Wed Jan 22, 2020"=>3}},
       {:name=>"FR-GP01", :data=>{"Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>5,
                                  "Thu Jan 23, 2020"=>4}}]
```

Note:

```
arr.group_by { |h| h[:name] }
  #=> {"FR-GP02"=>[{:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Mon Jan 20, 2020"=>2}},
                   {:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Mon Jan 20, 2020"=>5}},
                   {:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>1}},
                   {:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>3}},
                   {:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Wed Jan 22, 2020"=>1}}],
       "FR-GP04"=>[{:name=>"FR-GP04", :data=>{"Mon Jan 20, 2020"=>2}},
                   {:name=>"FR-GP04", :data=>{"Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>4}},
                   {:name=>"FR-GP04", :data=>{"Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>3}},
                   {:name=>"FR-GP04", :data=>{"Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>6}},
                   {:name=>"FR-GP04", :data=>{"Wed Jan 22, 2020"=>3}}],
       "FR-GP01"=>[{:name=>"FR-GP01", :data=>{"Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>5}},
                   {:name=>"FR-GP01", :data=>{"Thu Jan 23, 2020"=>3}},
                   {:name=>"FR-GP01", :data=>{"Thu Jan 23, 2020"=>1}}]}
```

`map`'s block variables initially equal the following:

```
k = "FR-GP02"
v = [{:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Mon Jan 20, 2020"=>2}},
     {:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Mon Jan 20, 2020"=>5}},
     {:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>1}},
     {:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>3}},
     {:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Wed Jan 22, 2020"=>1}}]
```

Then the value of `:data` in the first hash being created is computed as follows:

```
f = v.group_by do |h|
      h[:data].keys.first
    end
  #=> {"Mon Jan 20, 2020"=>[
  #      {:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Mon Jan 20, 2020"=>2}},
  #      {:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Mon Jan 20, 2020"=>5}}],
  #    "Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>[
  #      {:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>1}},
  #      {:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>3}}],
  #    "Wed Jan 22, 2020"=>[
  #      {:name=>"FR-GP02", :data=>{"Wed Jan 22, 2020"=>1}}]}
```

and lastly,

```
f.transform_values { |a| a.sum { |h| h[:data].values.first }}
  #=> {"Mon Jan 20, 2020"=>7, "Tue Jan 21, 2020"=>4, "Wed Jan 22, 2020"=>1}
```

---

Here is a second way to obtain the desired result.

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |g,h|
  d, n = g[:data].flatten
  h[[g[:name], d]] += n
end.group_by { |(name, _),_| name }
   .map do |name,arr|
     { name: name, data: arr.each_with_object({}) { |((_,d),t),h| h[d] = t } }
    end
  #=> (as above)
```

The steps are as follows.

```
s = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |g,h|
  d, n = g[:data].flatten
  h[[g[:name], d]] += n
end
  #=> {["FR-GP02", "Mon Jan 20, 2020"]=>7,
  #    ["FR-GP02", "Tue Jan 21, 2020"]=>4,
  #    ["FR-GP02", "Wed Jan 22, 2020"]=>1,
  #    ["FR-GP04", "Mon Jan 20, 2020"]=>2,
  #    ["FR-GP04", "Tue Jan 21, 2020"]=>13,
  #    ["FR-GP04", "Wed Jan 22, 2020"]=>3,
  #    ["FR-GP01", "Tue Jan 21, 2020"]=>5,
  #    ["FR-GP01", "Thu Jan 23, 2020"]=>4}
```

This uses the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes an argument called its *default value* (usually, as here, zero) and no block. If a hash is defined

```
h = Hash.new(0)
```

and--possibly after adding key-value pairs--does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` will return the default value. This means that in the expression

```
h[[g[:name], d]] += n
```

if `h` does not have a key `[g[:name], d]` the value of `h` for that key is initialized to zero before `n` is added. If `h` does have that key the current value of that key is increased by `n`.

Continuing the calculation,

```
t = s.group_by { |(name,_),_| name }
  #=> {"FR-GP02"=>[[["FR-GP02", "Mon Jan 20, 2020"], 7],
  #                [["FR-GP02", "Tue Jan 21, 2020"], 4],
  #                [["FR-GP02", "Wed Jan 22, 2020"], 1]],
  #    "FR-GP04"=>[[["FR-GP04", "Mon Jan 20, 2020"], 2],
  #                [["FR-GP04", "Tue Jan 21, 2020"], 13],
  #                [["FR-GP04", "Wed Jan 22, 2020"], 3]],
  #    "FR-GP01"=>[[["FR-GP01", "Tue Jan 21, 2020"], 5],
  #                [["FR-GP01", "Thu Jan 23, 2020"], 4]]}
```

Lastly,

```
t.map do |name,arr|
  { name: name, data: arr.each_with_object({}) { |((_,d),t),h| h[d] = t } }
end
  #=> (as above)
```

Here and earlier I've made good use of Ruby's powerful technique called [Array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition). See also [this article](https://jsarbada.wordpress.com/2019/02/05/destructuring-with-ruby/).

Comment: Yes, I saw that, thanks.

Comment: @Rajagopalan, as I said, there are many ways to solve this problem. Another way is to use the form of [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in two hashes being merged. You end up with a hash with keys equal to the values of `:name` and values equal to hashes with keys `:name` and `:data`, then take the values of that hash to get the desired array of hashes. You might consider working on an answer that uses that approach.

Comment: Yes, yes, thanks. I was trying to solve the problem, But I couldn't succeed it and I find you have posted the answer and it's helpful, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I understood how you have solved the problem, this must be the good one. Thanks. You are way older than me but you still got the energy to run faster than me :(

Comment: @Rajagopalan, if you are suggesting that I am old you are correct. One of my childhood memories is my mother taking me to the *Exposition Universelle* to see, among other things, the newly-constructed Eiffel Tower.

Comment: The best thing I noticed in you is, you don't care whether people accept your answer or not. You enjoy writing the answer. Great!

Comment: Thank you very much Cary for the incredibly in-depth response.  Definitely helps me with learning how things work instead of simply copy-pasting the code.  This will also help me in figuring out how to implement Groupdate into the situation!

Comment: One more comment to add that it turns out I didn't need to use Groupdate, and could instead just simply change the strftime in my first .map to `l.order.order_date.strftime('%Y-%m')` and everything still calculates properly